# how to forward a call to anther number in blackberry JDE

Tags: blackberry, contacts

am developing an blackberry application.. In my cantact list there are two groups 1.) Personal 2.) Work....... each having some contacts..

If a call comes from the group:personal means i want to forward to another number(which am giving)

and If a call comes from the group:Work means, i want to cut the call..

am new to this JDE, help me. .

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the supportforums. [Call-Control-functions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Call-Control-functions-like-answer-reject-disconnect-hold/m-p/23589).
The API is capable of initiating calls. Disconnecting a call need some kind of workaround. (e.g. KeyInjection)